# External static IP with Docker

Tags: networking, docker, subnet, bridge

I'm trying to set up a network bridge in Docker that is bridged to the external interface on the host machine.

I'm running Docker 10.11 on CentOS 7

This blog explains it well...

https://forums.docker.com/t/public-accessible-ip-in-container-like-bridge-network-in-virtualbox/3668/5

Here's the command I docker

I created the bridge according to the command here:

```
 sudo docker network create \
    --driver bridge \
    --subnet=192.168.33.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.33.10 \
    --opt "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="docker1" \
    shared_nw
```

I then added this to the external interface

```
sudo brctl addif docker1 eth1
```

I created a container and assigned it an IP on the network.

I can ping it without a problem from the host itself, but creating the docker bridge doesn't make the ip assigned to the bridge or the one assigned to the container accessible from another machine on the network and likewise the network itself isn't accessible.

I seems I'm missing something. I thought the bridge was suppose to allow for containers to use the same subnet as the host.

ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master docker1 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:aa:41:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feaa:4110/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:d9:cc:37:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.33.10/24 scope global docker1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:d9ff:fecc:37ff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 02:42:5c:8a:0f:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

brctl show

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.02425c8a0f57   no      
docker1     8000.0242d9cc37ff   no      eth1
```

Comment: Before you add `eth1` to the bridge, does it have an ip address on the 192.168.33.0/24 network?  Are you able to reach that address from other hosts on the network?  Are there other hosts on this network (specifically, using ips from the same range)?

Comment: No...the address was removed from the adapter and I removed the boot time script so it doesn't configure or grab one either.

Comment: Right.  But I was suggesting a test to perform that takes Docker out of the equation so that we can make sure this is a Docker configuration question vs. a basic system configuration question.  Maybe you could set that up and let us know the result?

Comment: To answer your question, yes it able to get to other hosts on the network and the other hosts on the network on in that range.

Comment: Okay.  And after adding `eth1` to the docker bridge, does (a) the `docker1` bridge have a valid ip address (e.g., one on that 192.168.33.0/24 network), and (b) are you *still* able to reach other hosts on that network?  Also, is `eth1` the only interface on your system connected to this particular network (that is, is there any chance your host is successful due to the configuration of another interface)?

Comment: (a) Yes (b) No, which is my problem. 

eth1 is the only interface on the system other lo (loopback).

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `ip addr` and `brctl show`?

Comment: I added these to the original posts.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I think I found what I was doing wrong. Apparently, after docker creates the bridge with the docker network create command, you have to add the bridge to the start-up script for whatever distro so it is brought up with whatever is managing the network. On Ubuntu, this required adding the bridge to the /etc/network/interfaces file and for CentOS this required adding a config file in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts folder.

After restarting the networking service (or rebooting) everything appears to work fine.